# aws cognito list users error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I´m getting the following exception when trying to list the users of a recently created Cognito User Pool

[image]

> Paging marker CAISlAIIARLtAQgDEugBAKNyAeHue5Tt46OPXc/9/PRAVKgprQocsrzhoPLlckx/eyJAbiI6IlBhZ2luYXRpb25Db250aW51YXRpb25EVE8iLCJuZXh0S2V5IjoiQUFBQUFBQUFCVER1QVFFQnQ0cTBlMFBBUmN1YWxKcjVmUkdEM0czMjZzMllzMHZBc2lFaldOV01jZE5sY0dZN01EbG1PV1JqTVRndE5qZGhaUzAwTVdSa0xXRXpNMk10T0RJNU5HUmxZemN6WlRZek93PT0iLCJwcmV2aW91c1JlcXVlc3RUaW1lIjoxNTA0MDE2MDQxMjg2fRogUVVeo3HVoNTzzNMyjFS9jEqE3CDuK9SMPYxemRt1EcY= is invalid for request 52373e32-8cc4-11e7-bf64-f1a6dfe5329c (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 52373e32-8cc4-11e7-bf64-f1a6dfe5329c)

I suspect it could be something related to a missing IAM role of my user, but couldn´t find anything, since in theory I´m an admin with full access.

EDIT:

actually, due to the "PAGING MARKER" text snippet, I suspect it could be simply a bug on amazon side related to pagination, since that pool has only one available user

Does anyone have a hint here?

Answer (score 3):

I am on the Cognito team and this is a console bug that we are in the process of fixing. This should be working by using the CLI.

Comment: This is still not fixed? Is there an issue to track this?